# Dynamically loading a part of a Window in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsview

I have an area of a Window (in my MainMenu.xib) which I'd like to populate dynamically with unrelated "views" such as an NSTable, IKImageBrowserView etc. at different points of time depending on some user-selected criteria.

- How do I define this area of the window such that it can be "replaced" with different views?
- How do I attach a table or some other view to this area of the window?

(Is it enough to place a generic NSView there and add a subview each time? I'm fairly new to Cocoa, so any pointers are welcome)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern Cocoa, this is the job of view controllers. [Cathy Shive](http://katidev.com/) has some good blog posts about them ([1](http://katidev.com/blog/2008/04/09/nsviewcontroller-the-new-c-in-mvc-pt-1-of-3/), [2](http://katidev.com/blog/2008/04/17/nsviewcontroller-the-new-c-in-mvc-pt-2-of-3/), [3](http://katidev.com/blog/2008/05/26/nsviewcontroller-the-new-c-in-mvc-pt-3-of-3/)), and co-authored [a more useful view controller class](http://katidev.com/blog/ktuikit/) than the basic NSViewController.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do it. I find it's easy to put in a "custom nsview", and replace it with the real view in windowDidLoad. It'd look something like this:

```
@interface MyController : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet NSView* dummyView;
}
@end

@implementation MyController
-(void)windowDidLoad{
    NSView* actualView = ...; //create the real view here
    [actualView setFrame:[dummyView frame]];
    [actualView setAutoresizingMask:[dummyView autoresizingMask]];

    NSView* superview = [dummyView superview];
    [dummyView removeFromSuperview];
    [superview addSubview:actualView];

    dummyView = actualView; //just incase dummyView is ever used again
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add 2 views for the 2 section. Say a topView and a bottomView link them to your code using the linking in interface builder. From there you can manage the content of each view with:

**addSubview** (is a function of the object that will receive the uiview or object)

you can use this to add individual objects or views to your two main views like:

```
[topView addSubview:roundedUIButton_instance];
```

OR

```
[topView addSubview:another_view_instance];
```

**removeFromSuperview** (is a function of an objects used to remove its self)

```
[roundedUIButton_instance removeFromSuperview];
```

OR

```
[another_view_instance removeFromSuperview];
```